# VKSdk.initialize error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, vk

I've added `compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:+'` in my dependencies and imported `import com.vk.sdk.VKSdk;` **But**, when I write `VKSdk.initialize(mVKSdkListener,appId);` it gives *cannot resolve symbol initialize* and gives me an **error** < identifier > expected. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk. To like sample says.

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize()` method shown in [the documentation](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk#sdk-initialization) takes three parameters. You are providing two.

Comment: can't find the method itself